# where to change the base class of the model made with doctrine in symfony?

Tags: php, model, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony to create a project (first project) and I read the documentation and all, and everything worked fine, I created with doctrine the classes that represents my DB, everything good, but then I need to change a field of the table, so, I went to symfony/lib/model/doctrine/base , find my class and I changed it, and done! worked fine.

The problem is when I need to make a new model using doctrine

```
php symfony doctrine:build-model
```

It takes my old models to the old version, and I get hundreds of errors, I think there is some other file to change, but I dont know where, any one could help me with this?

I already tried `php symfony cc` I am using symfony 1.4

Thanks.

Comment: If you start your first project with sf1.4, you should consider using sf2.2 instead which is the latest one. sf1.4 won't update in the future.

Comment: thank you, well, I am working adding modules on a project, it was made with symfony 1.4, but thanks, I will take in consideration for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @denys281 says, you don't have to touch Base classes since they are overrided every time your rebuild your model. You have already tested this case ..

If you want to update a field inside your database you have 2 options:

1. **You made the change**

   - modify your `config/doctrine/schema.yml` to update the field you want
   - rebuilt your classes `php symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`
   - update the field in your database **manually**
2. Let doctrine handle the change

   - modify your `config/doctrine/schema.yml` to update the field you want
   - run `php symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` to build difference between you previous schema and the new one
   - rebuilt your classes `php symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`
   - migrate the database using `php symfony doctrine:migrate`

You will find more information [about migrating in this capter](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/07-Migrations) which is for sf1.2 but it's ok for sf1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change base class!

You have in **lib/model/doctrine** files:

- **Name.class.php** and
- **NameTable.class.php**.

In **Name.class.php** you can write custom getter and setter, and  in **NameTable.class.php** you can write query for DB.

You can read more: [Day 3: The Data Model](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/03?orm=Propel) and [Day 6: More with the Model](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/06?orm=Doctrine)

Comment: This is a good reminder but this doesn't answer the question :)